# Facing issue while replacing substring in string in a dataframe using python 3.4.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, transformation

I have a dataframe `df1` which has column `srv_val`. I have to replace `0000000000` with only `0` if any string value in column `src_val` contains `0000000000`

Printing the column values in dataframe

```
print(srv_val)

0000000089.56
0000000023.45
0000000000.00
0000000000.89
0000000000.56
0000000000.00
```

Expected output: `0000000000` has to be replaced with `0` for those values which contain `0000000000`

```
print(src_val)
0000000089.56
0000000023.45
0.00
0.89
0.56
0.00
```

The solution I tried:

Trying to remove leading 9 zeroes if `0000000000` found but giving me compilation error

`df1['srv_val'] = df1['srv_val'].apply(lambda x:np.nan if pandas.isnull(x) else (x[9:] if "0000000000" in  x))`

or

`df1['srv_val'] = df1['srv_val'].apply(lambda x:np.nan if pandas.isnull(x) else (x[9:] if x.str.contains("0000000000")))`

Error:

`'str' object has no attribute  'str'`

Any help would be appreciated. I have to replace `0000000000` with `0` in that column in a dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they numbers better to change the datatype

```
df.srv_val.astype('float')
0    89.56
1    23.45
2     0.00
3     0.89
4     0.56
5     0.00
```

To get your expected output you can use `str.replace` with regEx `0{9}` to replace nine zeros with empty string `''`

```
df.srv_val.str.replace('0{9}','')
0    0000000089.56
1    0000000023.45
2             0.00
3             0.89
4             0.56
5             0.00
```

You got

> 'str' object has no attribute  'str'

Error as somewhere in your code you tried to call `str` on `string` type object.

Comment: you mean to say if I need to check for other things then I can use in this way ```df.srv_val.str.replace('0{9}','').apply(lambda x:np.nan if pandas.isnull(x) else (x[9:] if x.str.contains("0000000000")))```

Comment: I am proposing alternate way of doing this `df1['srv_val'].apply(lambda x:np.nan if pandas.isnull(x) else (x[9:] if x.str.contains("0000000000")))`

Comment: I wrote the same in my ques and getting error ```'str' object has no attribute  'str'```

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways to do this.

But before we start, Your values don't seem to be string to me, they are float, Why not use it as your advantage? It could speed up your process.

**Solution 1:**

```
df.loc[df['srv_val'].astype(float) == 0,'srv_val'] = "0"
```

If my above assumption is wrong, You have to do it with regex then and here are another 3 solutions. But I want you to remember, string replace are costlier comparative to float.

**Solution 2:** (Incase you want to replace only decimal 0's [any size])

```
df['srv_val'].str.replace(r'[0]+\.[0]+', '0')
```

**Solution 3:** (Incase you want to replace both decimal 0's and integer 0's [any size])

```
df['srv_val'].str.replace(r'[0]+(?:\.)[0]+', '0')
```

**Solution 3:** (Incase you have fixed size decimals to replace both decimal 0's and integer 0's)

```
df['srv_val'].str.replace(r'[0]{9}+(?:\.)[0]{2}+', '0')
```

Assuming its **(9).(2)**